# regex/preg_replace to extract the part number (substring)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm not very comfortable with RegEx.

---

#### The Use Case

I use three variables, namely `$url`, `$pattern` and `$replacement` and intend to use them as follows:

```
$url = $node->attr("href");

$resource = ExtractResourceWithoutHtmlExtension($url); // This is jus to abstract the stripping off of the prepended path and cutting the `.html` (see Edit 2 & 3 below).

$pattern =  ...
$replacement = ${1}; // Not very sure of this value

$partno = preg_replace($pattern, replacement, $resource);

echo '"'.$partno.'";"'.$node->attr("title").'";"'.$url.'"'."\n";
```

---

#### The Part number and Resouce scheme mapping (string)

- most of the time

`35000-0295` => designation-of-the-products-as-slug-**35000-0295**

`27021-0012` => designation-of-the-products-as-slug-**27021-0012**

- or rarely

`38811` => designation-of-the-products-as-slug-**38811**

- last but not the least (edge case => nothing to extract)
- In case of non availability of Part number, the Resource substring would be simply

`designation-of-the-products-as-slug`

I still prefer RegEx solution because there might be a variation in the length of number within the segments constituting the Part number.

---

#### The Question

What should I assign to `$pattern` and `$replacement`?

---

#### Edit 1 (for reference)

The substring `designation-of-the-products-as-slug` are mutable <strike>and path/to/ could be of any arbitrary depth</strike>.

#### Edit 2 (for reference)

On second thought I realise that there is no need to use RegEx for the whole URL path: *http://path/to/* could be stripped of using `parse_url`, `explode` and `array_pop`. Edited accordingly my post.

#### Edit 3 (for reference)

The the complexity could also reduce by cutting the immutable trailing substring `.html`. Cf. [@bloodyKnuckles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2743458/bloodyknuckles)'s comment below. Post edited accordingly.

Comment: *What should I assign to $pattern and $replacement?* I guess a value; Have you tired something?

Comment: Here's a (non-regex) idea: `$newurl = 'http://path/to/designation-of-the-products-as-slug' . ($partno? "-$partno": '') . '.html';`

Comment: @Rizier123 I suspect a value like '${1}' for `$replacement`. RegEx patterns are beyond my capacity for the time being: lack of knoledge and experience ;-)

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I forgot to mention that the substring `designation-of-the-products-as-slug` is mutable and `path/to/` could be of any depth. Will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: What does the URL look like before modification?

Comment: Undeterred, here's another (non-regex) idea: `$newurl = substr($url, 0, -5) . ($partno? "-$partno": '') . '.html';`, assuming your URLs always end in `.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with I'd use a combination of [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to strip off extraneous bits from the string, then use [`preg_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php) with a regex like `/.*?(\d+[\d-]*)$/` to grab the last chunk of digits plus optional following hyphens and digits.

---

#### Example:

```
$urls = [
    "http://example.com/path/to/designation-of-the-products-as-slug-35000-0295.extension",
    "http://example.com/path/to/designation-of-the-products-as-slug-35000.html",
    "http://example.com/path/to/designation-of-the-products-as-slug.ext?foo=bar.baz"
];

$regex = '/.*?(\d+[\d-]*)$/';

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $resource = pathinfo(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    echo preg_filter($regex, '$1', $resource), "\n";
}
```

---

#### Output:

```
35000-0295
35000
```

Comment: Thanx for your input! This comes close to what I expect. Could be the `$regex` tweaked so as to spit an empty string for the corner case touched in the 3rd line (No Part number to extract)?

Comment: Ok, that's allright, I've overlooked it :-) I reiterate my thanks and promise to learn RegEx the hard way ;-)